# query not displaying proper result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 project I have the following code for

1. My controller:

   ```
   class TasksController < ApplicationController

     def today
       @tasks = Task.today
       @task = Task.new
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html { render :text=> "Sorry , you don't have any task pending today." }

         format.html # new.html.erb
         format.xml  { render :xml => @tasks }
       end
     end

     def this_week
       @tasks = Task.this_week
       @task = Task.new
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html { render :text => "Sorry , No content for selected period." }

         format.html # new.html.erb
         format.xml  { render :xml => @tasks }
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. My model:

   ```
   class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

     def self.today
       Task.where(:due_date => "Date.today" , :task_status => "open").order("due_date ASC")
     end

     def self.this_week
       Task.where(:due_date =>"Time.now.this_week" , :task_status => "open" ).order("due_date ASC")
     end
   end
   ```

Why it does not displaying anything in the relative view. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why you have 2 `format.html`? maybe you miss the conditional? `if @tasks.blank? ... else ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `Task.where(...)`, you're passing in a string to `:due_date`, rather than a date. Remove the quotation marks:

```
Task.where(:due_date => Date.today, :task_status => "open").order("due_date ASC")
```

For your second one, there is no method called `Time.now.this_week`. You need to supply a `between` range instead:

```
Task.where("due_date between ? and ?", Date.today.beginning_of_week, Date.today.end_of_week").where(:task_status => "open").order("due_date ASC")
```